# List of Items with One Active Item Always Showing in BottomSheet Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

I want to use a BottomSheetScaffold to display a list of items in a bottom sheet and have something like an "alwaysVisibleSheetContent". All items share the same height with the exception of the active item (the always visible content) which will have a progress indicator below it. An item's height may vary (i.e. different font size in phone settings) and are not guaranteed to be 56dp which is the default value for sheetPeekHeight. It's possible that there is no active item in which case I want the always visible content to be some text. Either way the rest of the list is only made visible if the user drags the sheet up, and the sheet will only expand to as many items as there are. If there are more items than screen size the user can scroll through them. Any ideas for how to accomplish something like this?

I did try using onGloballyPositioned, BoxWithConstraints, and SubcomposeLayout but had trouble even getting the BottomSheetScaffold to recompose with the new peek height with either of them.

Let me know if I need to clarify anything. Any resources or ideas are welcomed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `sheetPeekHeight` by default it is `56.dp` so your `BottomSheetScaffold` will keep showing content of `56.dp` height.

[image: ref]

So you have to make it `0.dp` and It will be hidden completely.

Here is an example you can refer.

```
@Composable
fun BottomSheetExample() {

    val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState()

    BottomSheetScaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp,
        sheetContent = {
           //Sheet Content
        }
    ) { padding ->
       //Actual Screen Content
    }
}
```

I hope your problem is solved. Happy Compose!

Comment: Right, what if the content that should always be visible is not 56dp? I'll update my post to clarify this.

Comment: You can set ```peekHeight``` as per your choice or requirement.